# How to get an XML node value as string when deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am sending a XML to a aspnet core web api.   The value for the namespace prefix `cfdi:` is defined in a containing node:

```
<cfdi:Comprobante>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Addenda>
    <bfa2:AddendaBuzonFiscal version="2.0" xmlns:bfa2="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2"><bfa2:TipoDocumento nombreCorto="FAC" descripcion="Factura"/><bfa2:CFD totalConLetra="CINCUENTA Y DOS MIL QUINIENTOS OCHENTA Y NUEVE PESOS 64/100 M.N." observaciones="OBSERVACIONES"/><bfa2:Extra atributo="ClaveTransportista" valor="00328"/><bfa2:Extra atributo="NoRelacionPemex" valor="1-2"/>
    <bfa2:Extra atributo="NoConvenio" valor="5"/>
    </bfa2:AddendaBuzonFiscal>
    <Encabezado NumOrden="" NumFacturaOriginal="" FechaDePedido=""/>
    <Envio Calle="" NoExterior="" Colonia="" Localidad="" Municipio="" Estado="" Pais="" CodigoPostal="" NombreEnviar=""/><Detalle OrdenCompraLinea="10" GRNumber="GRN"/><Detalle OrdenCompraLinea="10" GRNumber="GRN"/><Detalle OrdenCompraLinea="10" GRNumber="GRN"/>
  </cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

To deserialize this I made the class `Comprobante`:

```
public class Comprobante : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [XmlArray("Conceptos"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Concepto), ElementName = "Concepto")]
    public List<Concepto> Conceptos { get; set; }

    public Addenda Addenda { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is mapped to the class properties but the `Addenda` node could receive anything -- any number of valid XML nodes -- so I don´t have a class definition.  I.e. the `Addenda` node could contain n nodes that I don’t know about, the information is validated in the recipient end. For example a customer could ask to add a node with a PO number, another could ask for buyer name. Etc.

If I need to get all the `Addenda` node content as string, how should I declare it in the class?

Comment: When you say "anything" do you mean literally anything? i.e are there more elements than you have shown us or elements you are unaware of?

Comment: Your XML is invalid -- the namespace prefixes `cfdi:` and `bfa2:` are undefined.  Can you give a valid example of what you are trying to do?  Is your XML really invalid?

Comment: This xml does not show the namespaces.  The addenda node, could contain n nodes that I don’t know about, the information is validated in the recipient end.  For example a customer could ask to add a node with a PO number, another could ask for buyer name. Etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize arbitrary, free-form XML data using `XmlSerializer` by marking target properties with [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx).

E.g. you can define your `Addenda` type as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("Comprobante", Namespace = "http://cfdi")]
public class Comprobante : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [XmlArray("Conceptos"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Concepto), ElementName = "Concepto")]
    public List<Concepto> Conceptos { get; set; }

    public Addenda Addenda { get; set; }
}

public class Addenda
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    [XmlText]
    public XmlNode[] Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [working .Net fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fsrzGJ).

Or, you could eliminate the `Addenda` type completely and replace it with an [`XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) property in the containing type:

```
[XmlRoot("Comprobante", Namespace = "http://cfdi")]
public class Comprobante : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [XmlArray("Conceptos"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Concepto), ElementName = "Concepto")]
    public List<Concepto> Conceptos { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement("Addenda")]
    public XmlElement Addenda { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [working .Net fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/02MGOE).

Notes:

- When applied *without* an element name, [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) specifies that the member is an array of `XmlElement` or `XmlNode` objects which will contain all arbitrary XML data that is not bound to some other member in the containing type.
- When applied *with* an element name (and optional namespace), [`[XmlAnyElement("Addenda")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x19181w6.aspx) specifies that the member is a either a single `XmlElement` object or an array of such objects, and will contain all arbitrary XML elements named `<Addenda>`.  Using this form eliminates the need for the extra `Addenda` type.
- Combining [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) with `[XmlAnyElement]` allows arbitrary mixed content to be deserialized.
- If you are using .NET Core you may need to nuget [System.Xml.XmlDocument](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/).